# MySQL Trigger Creation. What's wrong with my trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger, however I keep getting back a syntax error.

Here's the statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `swtalentbank`.`after_candidate_insert`  
    AFTER INSERT ON `Candidates` FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO useradmin (username, talent)  
        VALUES (NEW.email, 1);  
    UPDATE `Candidates` SET UserID = useradmin.userid where useradmin.username = NEW.email;
    END  

DELIMITER ;
```

I have a registration form on my site. When a person registers it populates the Candidates table with their profile information.

In the Candidates table, there are various fields, two of them being `'email'` and `'UserID'`.
`UserID is also the PK in 'useradmin'`, so I'm linking the two up.

So when a user registers, I need to insert a record into '`useradmin`' with the email address that's just been used to register, and then update the 'Candidates' table, with UserID that's just been created in '`useradmin`'.

I hope this makes sense?

NB. I am changing the delimiter before running the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Besides properly using `DELIMITER` when creating a trigger you have at least two fundamental issues with your current code:

1. In MySQL you can't use issue a DML statement (in your case `UPDATE`) against a table (`candidates`) on which you defined a trigger (also `candidates`). Your **only** option is to use `BEFORE` trigger and set a value of `userid` column of a row being inserted to a proper value.
2. You can't arbitrarily reference a column (`useradmin.userid`) of a table out of the context like you did in your `UPDATE`. You didn't joined `useradmin` table or used it in a subquery.

That being said and assuming that `userid` in `useradmin` table is an `auto_increment` column your trigger might look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_candidate_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON candidates
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO useradmin (`username`, `talent`) VALUES (NEW.email, 1);
  SET NEW.userid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58027/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You should use semicolon after end your insert query.

You can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax for your purpose

Comment: Just added that. I've updated my question to show exactly what I am running.

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `swtalentbank`.`after_candidate_insert`  
    AFTER INSERT ON `Candidates` FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO useradmin (username, talent)  
        VALUES (NEW.email, 1);  
    UPDATE `Candidates` SET UserID = useradmin.userid where useradmin.username = NEW.email;
    END $$  

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you, although I now get this: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$  

DELIMITER' at line 7 `